# systemd timer define 1s excute but leak 5s

Tags: systemd-timer

everyone , I define a foo.timer to excute foo.service every seconds

my OS version is centos7u2

```
#systemctl --version
systemd 219
-PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA -APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ -LZ4 -SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN

#systemctl cat  foo.timer
# /etc/systemd/system/foo.timer
[Unit]
Description=Run foo weekly and on boot

[Timer]
OnBootSec=15min
OnUnitActiveSec=1s
AccuracySec=1us


[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

look what I excute:

```
#systemctl cat  foo.service
# /etc/systemd/system/foo.service
[Unit]
Description=test

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/lib/aa.sh
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=journal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

script:

```
#cat /usr/lib/aa.sh
#!/bin/sh
aa=`date`
echo $aa >> /var/log/aa.log
```

log file:

```
Mon Jul 3 20:28:36 HDT 2017
Mon Jul 3 20:28:37 HDT 2017
Mon Jul 3 20:28:38 HDT 2017

Mon Jul 3 20:28:44 HDT 2017
Mon Jul 3 20:28:45 HDT 2017
Mon Jul 3 20:28:46 HDT 2017
Mon Jul 3 20:28:47 HDT 2017
Mon Jul 3 20:28:48 HDT 2017


Mon Jul 3 20:28:54 HDT 2017
Mon Jul 3 20:28:55 HDT 2017
Mon Jul 3 20:28:56 HDT 2017
Mon Jul 3 20:28:57 HDT 2017
Mon Jul 3 20:28:58 HDT 2017
```

look this log file ,we can see , I lost 5 seconds contents. I try to OnUnitActiveSec=2s , this problem not appear ,That's why ?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed systemd does not strictly follow timing, because of that I'm using this kind of timer, had no problems with it.

```
Description=Timer

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "while true ; do echo Timer; usleep 500000; done"
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
StartLimitInterval=0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Basically, it's a never ending loop, but for the sake of stability did set it to restart in 1 sec if it dies.

Comment: It's ok what you write , But , I just puzzled why what I write bellow have problem?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I think this might be related to some internal implementation of priorities in systemd.